# AutoMapper Custom Collections

Tags: automapper

I am getting an AutoMapper Exception when i try to Map my DomainModel to ViewModel,

Here is my Domain Model Class,

```
public class Source{

public string Name {get;set;}

..............

public CustomCollection EmpDetails {get;set;}

}

public class CustomCollection:CollectionBase,IEnumerable<ClassA> {

public CustomCollection{}

public int Add(ClassA classA)

{
  return List.Add(classA);
}

..........

}

public class ClassA{

public string EmpNumber {get;set;}

public string EmpName {get;set;}

public string Designation {get;set;}

}
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
public class SourceDTO{

public string Name {get;set;}

public IList<EmpDTO> EmpDetails {get;set;}


}

public class EmpDTO{

public string EmpNumber {get;set;}

public string EmpName {get;set;}

public string Designation {get;set;}

}
```

Here is my AutoMapper Code,

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Source, SourceDTO>()
            .ForMember(x => x.EmpDetails, y => y.MapFrom(src => src.EmpDetails));
```

I am getting error here, It doesn't say any detail inner exceptions,

I hope someone can help us out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a mapping to go from ClassA to EmpDTO:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ClassA, EmpDTO>();
```

And you should be all set.